# Why does eslint throw an error on a require statement?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, eslint

I've created a utility class via module.exports that uses [SSPI package](https://github.com/abbr/NodeSSPI) to get a user's NT name.

So far the class just requires `express` and `node-sspi` packages. Then an authenticate function invokes a request to get the user's NT name.

But when I build the solution this utility class throws an `eslint error` on line **3** where my first require assignment is defined:

```
var express = require('express');
```

Question:

Why does eslint throw an error on a require statement?

The detail of the error is as follows:

```
Message:
    Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ,
Details:
    fileName: src\js\util\requestLDAP.js
    lineNumber: 3
```

This is the gist of my utility class:

```
module.exports = {

  var express = require('express');
  var nodeSSPI = require('node-sspi');

  var nodeSSPIObj = new nodeSSPI({
    retrieveGroups: true
  }),

  authenticate: function () {
        nodeSSPIObj.authenticate(req, res, function(err){
        var ntUser = req.connection.user;
      })
  },
}
```

Comment: Basically, that is not valid JavaScript. You may wish to keep those variable declarations outside the object literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `var` inside an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals) to define properties.

```
var nodeSSPI = require('node-sspi');
var nodeSSPIObj = new nodeSSPI({ retrieveGroups: true });

module.exports = {
  express: require('express'),
  nodeSSPI: nodeSSPI,
  nodeSSPIObj: nodeSSPIObj,
  authenticate: function () {
    nodeSSPIObj.authenticate(req, res, function(err){
      var ntUser = req.connection.user;
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: That's correct although an xtra closing bracket is needed after the `authenticate` method I think.

Comment: The variables you reference need to be outside too, so they can be accessed.